# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addListener') & (reading 'sendMessage'). Using chrome.runtime in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Trying to send a message from an angular web application to an angular chrome extension.  Feels like chrome.runtime is not being initialized properly.

web application:

```
testClick(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("<extensionid>", "hello world");
}
```

service worker.ts

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

sendResponse("hello response");
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "example-chrome-extension",
  "short_name": "example-chrome-extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Generated with @larscom/ng-chrome-extension",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html?#/popup",
    "default_title": "Angular Chrome Extension"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "contentPage.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "serviceWorker.js"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  }
}
```

Is there more that is needed to initialize chrome.runtime other than what is here? I receive errors for both saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

Comment: Add `externally_connectable` as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thank you very much.